# How can I go about filtering a variable or file in autohotkey

Tags: loops, parsing, filtering, autohotkey, clipboarddata

I am trying to filter specific information to variable via parsing the clipboard but I need some help doing this.

```
Loop, parse, clipboard, `n, `r
 {
If A_LoopField contains XYZ
;Copy whatever text is found 2 or 3 lines below into file but continue on.
 }
```

Here is an example of whats

Clipboard =
(

- Line 1 - Blank
- Line 2 - XYZ *Some text telling my script to copy line 4 and so on*
- Line 3 - Blank
- Line 4 - "Text to be copied"
- Line 5 - Blank
- Line 6 - XYZ *Some text telling my script to copy lines 8 and so on*
- Line 7 . . .
  )

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if something like this is what you are looking for

```
cb =
(LTrim
    Line1
    Line2
    copy:5
    Line4
    Line5
    Line6
    copy:10
    Line8
    Line9
    Line10
    Line11
    Line12
)

copied := []    

Loop, parse, cb, `n, `r
{
    pos := (v:=strSplit(A_LoopField, ":")[2]) ? v:pos

    if (pos && A_Index >= pos){
        copied.push(A_LoopField)
    }
}

for k, v in copied
{
    msgBox % v
}
```